# Send event when time runs out Angular5

Tags: angular

In the child component I have a counter. I would like to report the parent component when the counter was clear. I made a few attempts but were unsuccessful.

timer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.scss']
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {

  private timeString : string;
  private duration = 5;
  private seconds = "--";
  private minutes = "--";   
  private clockDisplay : string;
  private interval: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tickTick(121)
  }

  tickTick(duration) {
    this.duration = duration
    if (this.duration > 0) {
      this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        this.duration = this.duration - 1
        if (this.duration <= 0) {
          clearInterval(this.interval)
        }
        if (this.duration % 60 < 10) {
          this.seconds = "0" + this.duration % 60
        } else {
          this.seconds = (this.duration % 60).toString()
        }

        if (this.duration / 60 < 10) {
          this.minutes = "0" + parseInt("" + this.duration / 60, 10)
        } else {
          this.minutes = "" + parseInt((this.duration / 60).toString(), 10)
        }

        this.clockDisplay = this.minutes + " : " + this.seconds;

        if(this.minutes === '00' && this.seconds === '00'){
          // I want send event when minutes and seconds == 0
        }

        document.body.innerHTML = this.clockDisplay
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

}
```

How can I cause the parent component to be notified when the counter zeroes?

Comment: Take a look at the official docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: I saw that. But I do not know how to fire the event. I can only make it work with a click of a button, and that's not what I want. What I want is for it to be fired when the counter zeroes

Comment: Just emit when the event when your counter reaches 0.

Comment: Okay. But I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[@Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)** decorator which provide a mechanism for a child component to emit events up to its parent component.

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

//...

export export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {


  @Output() timerEvent= new EventEmitter<any>();

   if(this.minutes === '00' && this.seconds === '00'){
          this.timerEvent.emit(value)//modify it accordingly
    }

  }
}
```

`EventEmitter` object has an `emit()` method that pushes the event up to the parent component.

In the parent component’s template, define event bindings as part of the child component’s selector. A binding should point to a method defined in the parent component’s class that takes action on the data received from the child. $event contains the payload emitted from the child:

Parent component template:app.component.html

```
 <timer (timerEvent)=onEvent($event)">
    </timer>
```

or you can directly assign the captured event to data property.

```
<timer (timerEvent)="data=$event">
        </timer>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public data: any;

  onEvent(data) {
        this.data = data;
      }
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. I had already done this, but I must have done something wrong, because I received no notification. thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Output from the child component to throw the event to parent component. See the example: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/quickstart/user-interaction-and-outputs/